# Unable to ssh from Machine2 to Machine1

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am trying ssh from my ubuntu VM2 to ubuntu VM1. Ping is working & ssh is active and ufw is also active.
But the ssh command timeout.

[image: ssh user@Machine1_ip_address (timeout occurred)]

The status of Machine2 is given below:

```
    osboxes@osboxes:~/virt-utils$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b5a8:7e0f:1980:254f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:31:40:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 388285  bytes 563502310 (563.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 99408  bytes 10177352 (10.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2009  bytes 281204 (281.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2009  bytes 281204 (281.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

osboxes@osboxes:~/virt-utils$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for osboxes:
Status: active
osboxes@osboxes:~/virt-utils$ service sshd status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled;
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-11-17 12:41:19 ES
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 29449 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited
 Main PID: 29466 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4544)
   Memory: 1.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─29466 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Nov 17 12:41:19 osboxes systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure
Nov 17 12:41:19 osboxes sshd[29466]: Server listening on 0.0
Nov 17 12:41:19 osboxes sshd[29466]: Server listening on ::
Nov 17 12:41:19 osboxes systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure S
lines 1-16/16 (END)
osboxes@osboxes:~/virt-utils$
```

Some body please guide me how to solve this problem. I am using bridged network on all my virtual machines.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow ssh, run

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

This will allow the default port for ssh (22).

For more information, [DigitalOcean has a rather good guide to UFW](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands).

Comment: Hi, I am now getting the error= ssh:connect to host 10.0.0.12 port 22: No route to host

Comment: Which error? What command? Can the machines ping eachother?

Comment: Yes. machine 2 to machine 1 ping is shown in the attached image. Second one I just tried and I got the message5 packets transmitted 0%packect loss, time 4013s. The above was the error related to= ssh osboxes.org@10.0.0.12

Comment: Sorry I was using the wrong user name. Login icon shows image of head and body with a text osboxes.org. So this deceived me and when i tried to search the password for root, I was able to find this problem. User name is osboxes and not osboxes.org. Password is osboxes.org. God bless you.